# setting up only image height attribute does not work in HTML, but setting up only width attribute works

Tags: html, markdown, hugo

I have met a strange problem. I am writing my blog post in Markdown. Occasionally, I need to include images and control and image size using HTML. I just include some HTML tags in Markdown. My code is like the following:

```
<p align="center">
<img src="https://blog-resource-1257868508.cos.ap-hongkong.myqcloud.com/20181225231628.png" width="200">
</p>
```

I found that setting the `width` attribute works as expected, but if I only set up the `height` attribute, the height attribute is ignored by the browser (tested both on chrome and safari).

I.E., the following HTML code does not work in setting up image height:

```
<p align="center">
<img src="https://blog-resource-1257868508.cos.ap-hongkong.myqcloud.com/20181225231430.png" height="200">
</p>
```

An example page is shown [here](https://jdhao.github.io/2018/12/25/my_reading_list_2018/). The first image is using height attribute only (`height="200"`), and the other images are using only width attribute (`widht="200"`). You can check the source code of the page to verify that.

[image]

BTW, I am using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) to generate the blog site for me. I do not if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your height in a style tag like this

```
<img src=“image.png” style=“height: 100px”>
```

You could also do something like this...

```
<p align="center">
<div class=imgContainer”>
<img src="https://blog-resource-1257868508.cos.ap-hongkong.myqcloud.com/20181225231628.png" width="200">
</div>
</p>
```

And

```
.imgContainer {
 Height: 100px;
Width: 200px;
}
```